# Any way to set project- or editor-wide highlight level instead of per-file?

Tags: clion

On my laptop, any highlighting level other than "None" cranks the CPU to max and gives me about 45 minutes of battery life as it saturates my CPU.   However, changing it with the little button in the bottom right is per-file.   So every time I go to a new file and forget to change it, my fan cranks up and my laptop heats up.

I don't want to turn on "power save mode" because then you don't get pop-up completions automatically.

I just want to set the "highlighting level" to "None" across the entire project or for the entire editor (I don't care which).

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Also, sometimes (when I'm plugged in), I do want to turn up the highlighting level for more detailed information, so it seems "configure inspections" isn't the right solution?  Or maybe I don't understand what that does.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create a new inspections profile.

Go into the settings, Editor -> Inspections. Create a new profile, and turn off everything.

When this profile is selected, you have behaviour equivalent to setting that per-file slider to "none". Switch it back to the default one when you want the proper inspections again.

Comment: I can't find any method other than using the dropdown in the Inspections settings screen. That said, it appears that if you click on the little inspector dude in the bottom-right of the editor, there is a link from there directly to that settings screen. That will save you a few clicks, at least.

Comment: There is also a keyboard shortcut for "disable inspection" but I'm not quite sure what the scope of it is.  It does seem to immediately stop inspections, as my CPU % goes way down almost immediately.. but I'm not sure if it's for the current file or what.

Comment: I thought that was for disabling a specific inspection, contextually (in the event you find some inspection annoying, you can press this when the caret on is something it has highlighted to shut it up)